# Swift: UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions scale factor set to 0 but not applied

Tags: ios, swift, scale, image-resizing, uigraphicscontext

I used to resize an image with the following code and it used to work just fine regarding the scale factor. Now with Swift 3 I can't figure out why the scale factor is not taken into account. The image is resized but the scale factor not applied. Do you know why?

```
let layer = self.imageview.layer

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.bounds.size, true, 0)

layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

print("SCALED IMAGE SIZE IS \(scaledImage!.size)")
print(scaledImage!.scale)
```

For example if I take a screenshot on iPhone 5 the image size will be 320*568. I used to get 640*1136 with exact same code.. What can cause the scale factor not to be applied?

When I print the scale of the image it would print 1, 2 or 3 based on the device resolution but will not be applied to the image taken from the context.

Comment: @LeoDabus already tried but it's not applied. I also tried UIScreen.main.scale.

Comment: @LeoDabus I've already checked your post before asking the question :) The question is not image specific it could be any layer. The issue is that this way to get an image from a graphic context has always applied the proper scale factor now it does not take it into account. It's more about why scale factor is not applied.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`scaledImage!.size` will not return the image size in pixel.

`CGImageGetWidth` and `CGImageGetHeight` returns the same size (in pixels)
That is `image.size * image.scale`

If you wanna test it out, at first you have to `import CoreGraphics`

```
let imageSize = scaledImage!.size //(320,568)
let imageWidthInPixel = CGImageGetWidth(scaledImage as! CGImage) //640
let imageHeightInPixel = CGImageGetHeight(scaledImage as! CGImage) //1136
```

Comment: Thanks for your relevant remark. In fact this has changed with Swift 3, it used to return the size pixel before so I get confused. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Updated for Swift 4.1:  
```let cgimage = scaledImage?.cgImage
print("Image size = \(scaledImage?.size)")
print("cgimage width = \(cgimage?.width)")
print("cgimage height = \(cgimage?.height)")```  
  And example result:  
```Image size = Optional((320.0, 320.0))
cgimage width = Optional(640)
cgimage height = Optional(640)```